# Days in month without weekends to xml files

Tags: c#, xml, datetime

I already found a way to create files for each day in month.

Like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> AllDatesInMonth(int year, int month)
{
    int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);

    for (int day = 1; day <= days; day++)
    {
        yield return new DateTime(year, month, day);
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
foreach (DateTime day in AllDatesInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month))
{
   //Blablabla
}
```

The files are named like 1.xml,2.xml,...

Now what I would to know is to do the same but with no files for the weekends (Saturday and Sunday).

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a linq to your method's result

```
foreach (DateTime weekDay in AllDatesInMonth(...).Where(d=>d.DayOfWeek!= DayOfWeek.Saturday && d.DayOfWeek!=DayOfWEek.Sunday)){

...
}
```

This way if you need to impose more conditions on the days included (holidays?) then you can add another .Where

Answer (score 2):

replace:

```
yield return new DateTime(year, month, day);
```

with:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(year, month, day);
if(dt.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && dt.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    yield return dt;
```

Of course, the method would have to be renamed to `AllWeekDaysInMonth`, since this change its intent. I actually like the other answer better.

Comment: This will cause DRY overrun - you'll have to modify the function every time you need it to do something else?

Comment: @StenPetrov I actually liked the other answer better because of this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the same code, just add a check for the day of week to the where loop:

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> AllDatesInMonth(int year, int month)
        {
        int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);

        for (int day = 1; day <= days; day++)
        {
            var dateToTest = new DateTime(year, month, day);
            if (dateToTest.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || dateToTest.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday) continue;
            yield return dateToTest;
        }
    }
```